# Two divs "inline", one with scaling image, one with comments

Tags: html, css

I'm loading a child-html-page into a colorbox (jquery plugin) to get a lightbox/modal effect when displaying images. But I want this html to have a picture in one div and to the right of it another div for comments.

I'm thinking two divs side by side. Two columns but not a table. The picture goes in one of them. Scaling to always fit (no scroll or hidden) and another div with matching height and fixed width.

One problem im having is simply putting to divs side by side. instead of scaling the pictures i get the two divs on different "rows". The first one pushing down the other.

Whats the method to keep them inline and scaling the width of the picture instead? I've tried float left/right, spans but i cant make it happen..

Answer (score 0):

Are the two columns fixed width? If so, you can use `display: inline-block;` and specify the width and heights. Then, for the image, use `width: 100%; height: auto;` on the `img` element itself.

Comment: No i was thinking that only the right one with comments should have a fixed width and that the left one with picture would be depending on the picture size. And that the pictures width always is fit so they together dont overflow the colorbox (80%). Damn it's hard even to explain this..

Answer (score 0):

Just float your div's and assign them a percentage width (50%, or less if you have margins and/or borders)

```
div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```